# Flutter Image picker issue

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to use image picker plugin for a flutter project. I am getting an error only in IOS.

```
2019-07-21 13:37:52.901660-0400 Runner[71283:10367169] flutter: 
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
```

Comment: Did you try ``flutter clean``?

Comment: Yes I did. I restarted the a couple of times also.

Comment: At times, Flutter can't find cocoa pod for the latest plug-in. Try following two things : A. Go to your iOS folder and run `pod install`. B. Lower image_picker plug-in version. (FYI : version image_picker: ^0.5.3 works well in one of my project)

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not include adding the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to the info.plist file.
please Add this in your info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your project Name </string>
```